# Inconsistent parsing with strptime in C?

Tags: c, time, strptime

Im encountering strange behavior when trying to use the strptime function in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __USE_XOPEN
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int parseTime(char *timestamp)
{

    time_t t1;
    struct tm *timeptr,tm1;
    char* time1 = timestamp;


    //(1) convert `String to tm`:  
    if(strptime(time1, "%Y/%j/%H/%M/%S",&tm1) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nInvalid timestamp\nTimestamp should be in the format: YYYY/DDD/HH/MM/SS\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }         

    //(2)   convert `tm to time_t`:    
    t1 = mktime(&tm1);

    return t1;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     int now = parseTime(argv[1]);  

     int wait = parseTime(argv[2]) - now;

     printf("%d\n", wait);


    return 0;
}
```

I run this program as ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

Heres some terminal output:

```
$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

3608

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

3608

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

8

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

8

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

8

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

8

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

3608

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

3608

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

8

$ ./timetest 2400/001/00/00/00 2400/001/00/00/08

3608
```

Is there something that I am missing that will produce these inconsistent results?

Comment: You return `time_t` in a function declared to return `int` .. these should match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that `tm` is not initialized before the use of `strptime`.

Initialize tm:
  `memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));`

[Documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) states that `tm` does not generally gets initialized before called by `strptime`. It depends on which implementation/UNIX system that you are using.